# Use Stack Overflow favicon on Stack Overflow Business

Tags: feature-request, favicon, stackoverflow-business

The current [Stack Overflow Business](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/) page is related to Stack Overflow.

[image]

However, it uses a [PNG](http://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/450622/favicon-144x144.png?t=1464901647867) as its browser icon.

[image]

It seems appropriate to use [the Stack Overflow favicon](http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=4f32ecc8f43d) instead.

Here is a view of the two sites' title bars (in Google Chrome), highlighting the difference in the icon format.

[image]

Comment: The same I already posted in [Meta SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322209/favicon-background-color-is-not-transparent-for-stack-overflow-business-page)

Comment: Cross-posted: [Favicon background color is not transparent for Stack Overflow Business page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/322209/914686)